# Why is there a mismatch in character encodings between when a POST request is sent and it is received?

Tags: java, servlets, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a java servlet that receives POST requests with data that is supposed to be encoded in UTF-8, but it appears to be encoded in ISO-8859-1.

For further clarification, here is some code samples:

In Java, when sending a PostRequest using Apache HttpClient:

```
PostMethod postMethod = new PostMethod(url);
postMethod.getParams().setContentCharset("UTF-8");

String bar = "\u200B\u200B\u200B\u200B\u200B\u200B\u200B";
postMethod.addParameter("body", bar);

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
int status = httpClient.executeMethod(postMethod);
```

On the receiving end (in the `doPost` method of HttpServlet):

```
String body = new String(req.getParameter("body").getBytes(), req.getCharacterEncoding());
```

In the above example, when I have a debug breakpoint where the request is sent, `bar.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8) = [-30, -128, -117, -30, -128, -117, -30, -128, -117, -30, -128, -117, -30, -128, -117, -30, -128, -117, -30, -128, -117]`. But when I inspect the string on the receiving end, even though the request is set to be in UTF-8 encoding, I only get the same result if I execute `bar.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)`.

So basically, When I send the string, it's being put into the paramaters as UTF-8, but it's being read out as ISO. In order to get the correct value for processing, I have to use `String utf8String = new String(bar.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1), StandardCharsets.UTF-8)`

Why is this happening? Is there some configuration that I'm missing somewhere? It should be noted that the sender and receiver are in different tomcat instances, possibly on the same machine, but not necessarily.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this already?

```
postMethod.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8")
```